# $l^{2}$ completness in the given norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let's consider a $l^{2}$ space, equipped with a norm $$||x||_{\infty} = \sup_{n}{|x_{n}|}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{2^{-n}|x_{n}|}$$ I would like to establsh, whether the space is complete in the given norm.

I've proved that $||x||_{2^{-n} \infty} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{2^{-n}|x_{n}|}$ is bounded above by $C\cdot ||x||_{2}$ (which can be done applying Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwartz inequality), but it does not help much, since it does not imply even the completness in this norm. Moreover, i'm familiar with the fact that $||x||_{\infty}$ norm makes $l_{\infty}$ space into a complete one, but this does not help too, not least because $l_{\infty}$ is a much bigger space.

Are there any hints that might help?

Comment: Note that your norm is equivalent to the usual supremum norm. Do you happen to know what the closure of $\ell^2$ in $\ell^{\infty}$ is?

Comment: No, it's smaller. All elements of $\ell^2$ are sequences converging to $0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Well, still i'm trying to figure it now, supposing that it can't be $l^{2}$ itself.

Comment: @DanielFischer The space should consist of all sequences with their tails tending to 0.

Comment: Also known as $c_0$. Indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider the sequence $v_m=(1,1/2,1/3, \cdots , 1/(m-1),1/m, 0,0,0,\dots).$